# Use Reference Documents for Lookups - Couchbase

Tags: nosql, couchbase

Does anyone have an example related to reference documents for couchbase?

I have found this example: http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-devguide-2.0/reference-docs-and-lookup-pattern.html

But I need an example for the Java SDK.

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with that example? Java SDK functions have same names and they work in the same way, there is no such big difference between SDKs. Have you tried just to write that sample on java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing special here, as M03geek stated in his comment you have to do the same using the Java SDK.

I have created a gist for you:

- https://gist.github.com/tgrall/6105234